# Sign In by selecting button through Selenium in Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, button, css-selectors

I am trying to sign in my account through [this link](https://sso.accounts.dowjones.com/login?state=g6Fo2SBQQURPVkxkcTR0RW1zX21NSmxLY3F4Q2RoUm5QTWV4UaN0aWTZMmdhRm8yU0IwUW01dVV6WjJiVXhVUmtaRVRXd3dlamM1UVdjNVIweExiVFJVYlc5WFl3o2NpZNkgNWhzc0VBZE15MG1KVElDbkpOdkM5VFhFdzNWYTdqZk8&client=5hssEAdMy0mJTICnJNvC9TXEw3Va7jfO&protocol=oauth2&prompt=login&scope=openid%20idp_id%20given_name%20family_name%20email%20djid%20prts&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.marketwatch.com%2Fauth%2Fsso%2Flogin&nonce=ac689d94-8b8f-4e6d-9255-439f58fc3c0f&connection=DJldap&ui_locales=en-us-x-mw-3-8&ns=prod%2Faccounts-mw#!/signin) on the Market Watch web page through Python and using the Selenium package. I am able to select the "Sign In" button and click on it but nothing happens and therefore can't access the webpage I want.

I think my mistake comes from the fact that I am perhaps not selecting the correct button. The element code is the following:

```
<div class="sign-in">
    <button class="solid-button basic-login-submit">
        <span class="text" data-token="signIn" token-title="signIn" title="Sign In">
        Sign In
        </span>
    </button>
</div>
<div class="create-connect" style="display: none;">
    <button class="solid-button basic-login-connect">
        <span class="text" data-token="yesConnect">
        Yes, connect
        </span>
    </button>
    ...some other buttons for facebook connection
```

My code is the following:

```
    driver.get("https://sso.accounts.dowjones.com/login?state=g6Fo2SBQQURPVkxkcTR0RW1zX21NSmxLY3F4Q2RoUm5QTWV4UaN0aWTZMmdhRm8yU0IwUW01dVV6WjJiVXhVUmtaRVRXd3dlamM1UVdjNVIweExiVFJVYlc5WFl3o2NpZNkgNWhzc0VBZE15MG1KVElDbkpOdkM5VFhFdzNWYTdqZk8&client=5hssEAdMy0mJTICnJNvC9TXEw3Va7jfO&protocol=oauth2&prompt=login&scope=openid%20idp_id%20given_name%20family_name%20email%20djid%20prts&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.marketwatch.com%2Fauth%2Fsso%2Flogin&nonce=ac689d94-8b8f-4e6d-9255-439f58fc3c0f&connection=DJldap&ui_locales=en-us-x-mw-3-8&ns=prod%2Faccounts-mw#!/signin") #this is the link above 

username = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("password")

username.send_keys("myemail@hotmail.com")
password.send_keys("***")

driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[contains(text(), 'Sign In')]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[contains(text(), 'Yes, connect')]").click()
```

Where the first element is supposed to on the sign in button. I am not sure about the second click but I stilled tried it and still nothing happened.

I am interested to find out:

1. what am I doing wrong
2. why when I click on the "Sign In" button nothing happens
3. how to get over it

I have also tried without success:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("solid-button.basic-login-submit")
```

Comment: From the look of the HTML on that page, the `<form>` has no action attribute, so I bet JavaScript is listening for an onclick or onsubmit event. Clicking this using Selenium might not be triggering DOM events correctly. You might want to try triggering a click event using JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your try is very close. Changing the code from your attempt to

```py
# You'll need to import these dependencies
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

button = WebDriverWait(driver,1000).until(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button.solid-button.basic-login-submit")

button.click()
```

`WebDriverWait(0,1000)` makes the program search for the element for 1000 seconds. This is better because it gives the page time to load.

Comment: Now it does not work, `username.send_keys` would also be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try use following code.This should work.Provide WebdriverWait after inserting value in the test field

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://sso.accounts.dowjones.com/login?state=g6Fo2SBQQURPVkxkcTR0RW1zX21NSmxLY3F4Q2RoUm5QTWV4UaN0aWTZMmdhRm8yU0IwUW01dVV6WjJiVXhVUmtaRVRXd3dlamM1UVdjNVIweExiVFJVYlc5WFl3o2NpZNkgNWhzc0VBZE15MG1KVElDbkpOdkM5VFhFdzNWYTdqZk8&client=5hssEAdMy0mJTICnJNvC9TXEw3Va7jfO&protocol=oauth2&prompt=login&scope=openid%20idp_id%20given_name%20family_name%20email%20djid%20prts&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.marketwatch.com%2Fauth%2Fsso%2Flogin&nonce=ac689d94-8b8f-4e6d-9255-439f58fc3c0f&connection=DJldap&ui_locales=en-us-x-mw-3-8&ns=prod%2Faccounts-mw#!/signin") #this is the link above

username = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("password")

username.send_keys("myemail@hotmail.com")
password.send_keys("***")
WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@class='solid-button basic-login-submit']"))).click()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try  :

```
 driver.find_element_by_class_name('sign-in')
```

Answer (score 0):

Even after the sign in button was clicked I was not signed in. I used the "login" href link from "https://www.marketwatch.com/" and this worked.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from time import sleep


driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\\Py\\geckodriver.exe');

# driver.get('https://sso.accounts.dowjones.com/login?state=g6Fo2SBJbUhZMUdPZlJfOEJSRWgxLVVFNXhoR3E5cFdaVlI4dKN0aWTZMmdhRm8yU0JaV0ZCWVluSmxNM2c0UjJSVk4wNXFlSHByUW5SUU1sRnpjMjFDVkVoeFNno2NpZNkgNWhzc0VBZE15MG1KVElDbkpOdkM5VFhFdzNWYTdqZk8&client=5hssEAdMy0mJTICnJNvC9TXEw3Va7jfO&protocol=oauth2&prompt=login&scope=openid%20idp_id%20roles%20email%20given_name%20family_name%20djid%20djUsername%20djStatus%20trackid&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.marketwatch.com%2Fauth%2Fsso%2Flogin&nonce=4b5092ee-62d1-47cb-a16e-2ceb396b059c&connection=DJldap&ui_locales=en-us-x-mw-0&mg=ss-ngx#!/signin')
driver.get('https://accounts.marketwatch.com/login?target=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.marketwatch.com%2F')

sleep(5)

username = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("password")

username.send_keys("myemail@hotmail.com")
password.send_keys("***")

sign_in = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='basic-login']/div[1]/form/div/div[7]/div[1]/button")

sign_in.click()
```